# Finding Riesz basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be a Hilbert space .Is there always a non orthogonal Riesz basis $D$ on it such that following holds?

$$\sup_{g\in D }\sum_{g'\in D,g'\not=g}|\langle g,g'\rangle|<1/3 $$

And is there  Riesz such that the inequality does not hold?

Comment: There is only one Riesz, and he satisfies $1880\le\text{Riesz}\le1956$.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a link to proof or sketch of proof?

Comment: I wanted to construct it using orthonormal basis of H

Comment: But for an orthonormal basis you even have $\sup_{g\in D }\sum_{g'\in D,g'\not=g}|\langle g,g'\rangle|=0$?

Comment: oh yes:) it is true, I am interested on a basis which is not orthonormal.  Actually I am interested on pure greedy algorithms in Riesz basises, I am interested is there any Riesz basis such that convergence rate for PGA will be less than -1/2

Comment: It's usually a good idea to state in the original question what you're actually interested in.

Comment: @joriki: there's at least a [second Riesz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Riesz) (younger brother) and he satisfies $1886 \leq \text{M. Riesz} \leq 1969$. :-)

Comment: ok, now I see meaning these numbers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$. For each $j\in J$ we denote by $j+1$ some fixed element different from $j$ (it can actually be $j+1$ if $J=\mathbb N$).

Define
$$
f_j=e_j+\frac18\,e_{j+1},\ \ j\in J.
$$
The set $\{f_j\}$ clearly spans $H$. Also,
$$
\left\|\sum_jc_jf_j\right\|^2=\sum_{j,k}\langle c_je_j+\frac{c_j}8e_{j+1},c_ke_k+\frac{c_k}8e_{k+1}\rangle=\sum_j|c_j|^2+\frac18\,\sum_j|c_j|^2+2\text{Re}\,\frac18\,\sum_jc_j\overline{c_{j+1}}.
$$
Note that, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $|\sum_jc_j\overline{c_{j+1}}|\leq\sum_j|c_j|^2$. Then
$$
\left\|\sum_jc_jf_j\right\|^2\leq\frac98\sum_j|c_j|^2+\frac14\,\sum_j|c_j|^2=\frac{11}8\sum_j|c_j|^2.
$$
Also,
$$
\left\|\sum_jc_jf_j\right\|^2\geq\frac98\sum_j|c_j|^2-\frac14\,\sum_j|c_j|^2=\frac{7}8\sum_j|c_j|^2.
$$
All this shows that $\{f_j\}$ is a Riesz basis.

Finally, for any $j\in J$,
$$
\sum_{k\ne j}|\langle f_k,f_j\rangle|=\frac18|\langle f_{j+1},f_j\rangle|+\frac18|\langle f_j,f_{j+1}\rangle|=\frac18+\frac18<\frac13.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I just did not  understand the last inequality, where did the sum go after equality sign?

Comment: There were a few typos that I corrected. But there is no sum, only two of the inner products are nonzero.

Comment: ok, I got it, thank you very much